# Fetch numeric from a sentence and calculate average.

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, numpy

I have a sheet with following data :

```
team1,team2,outcome
AA,BB,BB won by 90 runs
AA,CC,AA won by 19 runs (D/L method)
CC,BB,CC won by 26 runs (D/L method)
AA,BB,BB won by 56 runs
CC,BB,CC won by 18 runs
```

I need to pick the numeric value and calculate avg of them grouped by team1,team2.

This is what is have till now. Lot of junk data therefore i filter needy records only !

```
 df[df['outcome'].str.contains('runs',na=False)].head()
```

My desired outcome :

```
team1 , team2 , AVG(NUMERIC COLUMN FROM 'OUTCOME')
```

Please suggest !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with casting to `int` first, then `groupby` and aggregate `mean`:

```
df.outcome = df.outcome.str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False).astype(int)
print (df.groupby(['team1','team2'], as_index=False)['outcome'].mean())
  team1 team2  outcome
0    AA    BB       73
1    AA    CC       19
2    CC    BB       22
```

Similar solution:

```
s = df.outcome.str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False).astype(int)
print (s.groupby([df['team1'],df['team2']]).mean().reset_index())
  team1 team2  outcome
0    AA    BB       73
1    AA    CC       19
2    CC    BB       22
```

Comment: Thanks , i will try this out . Could you please tell what is significance of expand = False ?

Comment: It is only for warning, `FutureWarning: currently extract(expand=None) means expand=False (return Index/Series/DataFrame) but in a future version of pandas this will be changed to expand=True (return DataFrame)`